# PHP Get text between multiple <h1>...</h1> tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a page with multiple H1 headings followed by text and so on.
Example:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>Some text here
<h1>Title 2</h1>Some more text here
<h1>Title 3</h1>Even more text here
```

etc

What I want to do is create an array of elements, that is explode the HTML using as separator `<h1>ANY TEXT</h1>` above that I have in an $output variable.

The final purpose is to count the strlen of the text between the ending `</h1>` and next starting `<h1>` and if it's higher than 200 characters to hide it inside a `<span>` with `display:none` so users can press "Show all" to unhide that.

How can I get that please?

Comment: Sounds like client side JavaScript will help you out here.

Comment: [You should drop regex and use a parser instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: give them an ID and the use getelementbyid()

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SimplePHPDom to do this before sending the page out to the client:

```
ob_start();
// build page here
$html = ob_get_clean();

$dom = str_get_html($html);

$headings = $dom->find('h1');

foreach($headings as $h1) {
   // process node to add CSS to hide node and change text to 'show more'
}
```

This could also be done client-side with jQuery/MooTools, with basically the same process (minus the buffering capture stuff).

Comment: I think OP wants to analyze the text that comes **after** the H1 tags... `text between the ending </h1> and next starting <h1>`

Comment: Ah yes... d'oh... Mondays... In that case, `$h1->nextSibling()` would probably come into play within the `foreach()`